# Liferay search button showing the source code

Tags: java, html, liferay

I am trying to integrate the search functionality in liferay. I have used `$theme.search()` in my theme and have allowed the web-content display in my `portal-ext.properties` file. But, while I am pressing the web-content after searching it, it is displaying the source code. Any idea?
below is the content in portal-ext file :

```
com.liferay.portlet.blogs.util.BlogsOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.bookmarks.util.BookmarksOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.calendar.util.CalendarOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.directory.util.DirectoryOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.DLOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.imagegallery.util.IGOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.journal.util.JournalOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.util.MBOpenSearchImpl=true

com.liferay.portlet.wiki.util.WikiOpenSearchImpl=true
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it in detail? What property do you have set in `portal-ext.properties` and what code does it show when you press `Search` button?

Comment: it shows the actual html code of the webcontent .